# Python downloading a file from button on website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Im trying to download a file from this [website](https://www.ccee.org.br/portal/faces/pages_publico/o-que-fazemos/como_ccee_atua/precos/preco_horario) using the request library, but i cant figure out how to activate a button to download a "XLS" file using some date parameters.

i want to download this file without using the browser.

when inspecting the button i get this code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGerarPrecoHorarioXls" onclick="gerarPrecoHorarioXls();return false;">Gerar Arquivo&nbsp;&nbsp;<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-file-excel-o fa-2">&nbsp;</i></button>
```

when activating the button it seems that a js is started on the network tab.

but i dont know how to insert the parameters so it return the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium to click items on a webpage.
For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("Right click on the item, choose inspect, then right click, copy xpath and put it in here.")[0]
button.click()
```